# Nginx. Multiple sites on the same server causes Cloudflare Error 1000. DNS points to prohibited IP

Tags: nginx, webserver, cloudflare

I got 2 domains.

domain1.com and domain2.com both take place on Cloudflare nameservers and linked to the one server ( A records of the same ip).

But when I'm trying to configurate two sites on the single server. I got Cloudflare error 1000

I make setup nginx for the first domain. Created the conf file in sites-available and linked it to sites-enabled.
Here is the domain1.conf that stores in sites-available and linked to sites-enabled.
domain1.conf:

```
server {

server_name domain1.com, www.domain1.com;
listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://somehost/;
        proxy_redirect default;
                }
}

server {

server_name domain1.com, www.domain1.com;
listen 443 ssl;


    location / {
        proxy_pass https://somehost/;
        proxy_redirect default;
                }

ssl_certificate crt;
ssl_certificate_key key;
}
```

It works perfectly.
Also, with this confinguration file, when I'm trying to access domain2.com it shows me the domain1.com content.

And when I'm trying to create domain2.conf file in sites-available, and link it to sites-enabled, I'm recieving the Cloudflare error 1000 on both sites.

domain2.conf:

```
server {

server_name domain2.com, www.domain2.com;
listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://someotherhost/;
        proxy_redirect default;
                }
}

server {

server_name domain2.com, www.domain2.com;
listen 443 ssl;


    location / {
        proxy_pass https://someotherhost/;
        proxy_redirect default;
                }

ssl_certificate crt;
ssl_certificate_key key;
}
```

Also, when I'm trying to cat both files in a single domain1-2.conf file, I got the same error.

There is no other files or links in sites-available and sites-enabled.
The server is ubuntu20.04
I need to work multiple sites on single server. What am I doing wrong?